# БД в Delphi: связка таблиц

Tags: delphi

Прошу, пожалуйста, помочь.

У меня тема курсача - программа для видеопроката, имеются 2 тейбла, в 1-м тэйбле будут жанры, я так думаю, а во 2-й название фильма, жанр, кто забрал, с какого числа, по какое число, выдан в прокат или нет.

Как мне связать две таблицы по каким ключам, чтобы можно было в 1-й таблице выбрать жанр, и во 2-й таблице выбило бы все фильмы этого жанра.

Надеюсь на вашу помощь. =)

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю так: первая таблица (главная) : ID (ключ), название фильма, жанр (число) и т. д., и другая таблица жанр, где ID (ключ) и название жанра. В поле главной таблицы жанр нужно писать ID жанра и в ней создать подстановочное поле, чтобы название жанра отображалось, а не его номер. Таблицы в Delphi связываются с помощью свойства MasterSource компонентов (Table, ADOTable), а поле главной таблицы (поле, по которому связывать) - свойство MasterField. Если версия Delphi 7, то там можно проще: через схему данных (diagram). Кстати, чуть не забыл, не всегда поля связи в Delphi можно делать подстановочными. Так что придётся определиться: что именно нужно. Мне кажется, что нужно создать подстановочное поле (Lookup Field) в наборе данных Table. Выборку по жанру можно сделать с помощью фильтрации или SQL запроса.

Comment: спс за помощь...но фильтрацию через что делать лушче?,и как сделать подстановочное поле)если можно опишите)

Comment: Выбрать таблицу (Table) нажать правой мышью и выбрать пункт Add All Fields... (если нет всех полей), а добавить New Field, там выбрать тип Lookup Field, назвать поле (задать Field Name), указать тип (в данном случае строковый), выбрать источник данных подстановки (Lookup Data), keyFields - поле - номер жанра, LookupKeyFields поле ID жанра, ResultField - поле название жанра (в Вашем случае). Подробнее можно почитать на кусе Интуита http//:www.intuit.ru: там курс есть "Программирование баз данных в Delphi".

Answer (score 0):

Уважаемый [[@DelphiM0ZG](/users/3565/delphim0zg)](/users/3565/delphim0zg) и я так и не поняли, что Вы имеете ввиду: интерфейс Вашей программы или схему таблиц в БД.

Схема таблиц 1)таблица-справочник (родитель) ЖАНР: ID_жанр, Название.  2)Бизнес-таблица (ребенок) с названиями фильмов должна содержать внешний ключ, указывающий на ID_жанр первой таблицы.

Интерфейс: все, как пишет уважаемый [[@DelphiM0ZG](/users/3565/delphim0zg)](/users/3565/delphim0zg), с заменой слова "таблица", например, на "DBGrid".

Comment: спс ребята)помогли,если будет чо не понятно буду знать куда бежать)

Comment: Я имел ввиду набор данных (Table), а не интерфейс.